# Turning working code into macro causes "Missing number, treated as zero --- \let"

Tags: macros

Here's a minimal working example (MWE):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\noindent\minipage[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\lstlisting
  foo
\endlstlisting
\endminipage \qquad \minipage[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\lstlisting
  bar
\endlstlisting
\endminipage

\end{document}
```

Since I'm using this pattern a lot (code on left transforms into code on right), like a good programmer I encapsulate it in a macro:

```
\newcommand{\twocol}[2]{
\noindent\minipage[t]{0.45\linewidth}
  #1
\endminipage \qquad \minipage[t]{0.45\linewidth}
  #2
\endminipage
}
```

And try this in my document:

```
\twocol{
\lstlisting
  foo
\endlstlisting
}{
\lstlisting
  bar
\endlstlisting
} %% line 33, see below
```

At which point LaTeX is unhappy:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
    \let 
l.33 }
```

Line 33 is the closing bracket of the `twocol`. This is just a simple textual substitution (I copy-pasted the listings commands) so what's going wrong, and how do I fix it?

Note: using the `\begin{} ... \end{}` forms everywhere doesn't help.

Comment: You can't put lstlisting and its content in the argument of a command. lstlisting has to do a lot of catcode magic.

Comment: Why are you using environments via their underlying macros?  You should use `\begin` and `\end` unless you're trying to build a new environment around them.  If for no other reason than that the envrionment *may* set local variables that it expects not to be global because `\begin...\end` protects them in a group.

Comment: Thanks - no-one's ever pointed that out to me; according to some TeX tutorial I read "the two forms are equivalent" so I chose the shorter one - apparently not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about building this up piece by piece as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{listings}

\newenvironment{twocol}{\noindent\minipage[t]{0.45\linewidth}}{\endminipage}  
\newcommand{\twcbr}{\endminipage\qquad\minipage[t]{0.45\linewidth}}

\begin{document}

\begin{twocol}
\lstlisting
  foo
\endlstlisting
\twcbr
\lstlisting
  bar
\endlstlisting
\end{twocol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works (but looks weird!) Is there a reason that endtwocol is a \def rather than a \newcommand ?

Comment: `\newcommand` doesn't allow you to define commands starting with `end` as these are meant for ends of environments.  However, I have now rephrased my answer using a standard `\newenironment` instead.